# Python string substitution for dynamic column name and values

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psql

I have following query to retrieve data from PostgreSQL.

```
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM kart_user WHERE token = %(token)s"
cursor.execute(select_stmt, { 'token': 2 })
```

Some case dictionary may contain multiple keys and values 
Eg-

```
{ 'token': 10,'custid':100,cycle:"yes" }
```

In this case how i can dynamically specify the column name and its values??

I have tried..

```
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM kart_user WHERE dist.keys() = %(dist.keys())s"
cursor.execute(select_stmt, dist)
```

But no luck. Thank you for your response..

Comment: did you try to iterate through the key-value pairs and add them one by one to the SQL string?

Comment: I have already  thought that way , please suggest some other better way to solve this issue .thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your tried statement, I assume you have three keys and three values so you want to execute SELECT statement for all three one by one. Below solution will help you.

```
d = { 'token': 10,'custid':100,cycle:"yes" }
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM kart_user WHERE {key} = '{value}'"
allowed_col = ['token', 'custid'] # Predefined column names to allow from coming dictionary.
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if  key in allowed_col:
        select_stmt = select_stmt.format(key=key, value=value)
        cursor.execute(select_stmt, dist)
        # Further fetching code you can execute. Here you will get select statement for particular key and value.
```

@ For **and** conditions

```
d = { 'token': 10,'custid':100,'cycle':"yes" }
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM kart_user WHERE"
allowed_col = ['token', 'custid'] # Predefined column names to allow from coming dictionary.
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if  key in allowed_col:
        condition = "{key} = '{value}'".format(key=key, value=value)
        select_stmt = select_stmt + " and " + condition
cursor.execute(select_stmt, dist)
# Further fetching code you can execute. Here you will get select statement for particular key and value.
```

One liner solution for above answer,

```
d = { 'token': 10,'custid':100,'cycle':"yes" }
condition = ' and '.join([key+'="'+str(value)+'"' for key,value in d.iteritems() if key in allowed_col])
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM kart_user WHERE"
select_stmt = " ".join([select_stmt, condition])
cursor.execute(select_stmt, dist)
# Further fetching code you can execute. Here you will get select statement for particular key and value.
```

If your query is different then what I answered then reply on this. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on where the dictionary data comes from this method is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: That is right, so to protect that we can prepare one list of allowed columns only and just add one if condition in for loop.

Comment: what is ?? allowed_col = ['token', 'custid']

Comment: Those are column names of the table taken from your example.

Comment: column name is specified in the dist itself

Comment: This 'allowed_col' list is only required to avoid SQL injection. Otherwise you can remove that if condition and this list is not required.

Comment: yes it was worked for only single column and its values , what about and condetions